# Exit of TFS in Visual Studio without causing a problem

Tags: tfs

Sorry that my question is beginner. I intend to leave `TFS` without making any problem for the `MVC` project, and continue to work locally

What do I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by leaving TS without making any problem for the MVC Project ? Are you taking about exiting from Visual Studio ?

Comment: @Jayendran Disconnect from TFS (Team Foundation Server) and working as offline(without any dependencies to server)

Comment: Disconnect the TFS where ? like browser/Visual studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control:

[image]

Unbind the soultions/projects:

[image]

**Now the solution/project not connected to TFS.**

Before the "unbind" you can see the TFS icons:

[image]

And now the icons are gone:

[image]